# "Cannot use None as a query value" in django search filter showing this error

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement search bar in django, if search item present in Database i'm displaying in web page. But its showing query returns None value. I'm new to django.Please help me in this

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            search_query = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
            print(search_query)
            FirstLoc_list_obj = FirstLoc_List.objects.filter(address__icontains=search_query)
            SecondLoc_list_obj= SecondLoc_list.objects.filter(address__icontains=search_query)
            if (len(FirstLoc_list_obj) or len(SecondLoc_list_obj)) > 0:
                print("Locaton Found")
                return render(request, 'location_test.html', {'FirstLoc_list_obj': FirstLoc_list_obj, 'SecondLoc_list_obj': SecondLoc_list_obj})
            else:
                print("Location Not Found")
                return render(request, 'location_test.html', {})
            return render(request, 'location_test.html', {})
        return render(request, 'location_test.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', views.search, name="search"),
]
```

location_test.html

```
<form type="get" action="#" style="margin: 0">
    {% csrf_token %}
<label>Locations:-</label>
    <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
    <button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the result of **`print(search_query)`**?

Comment: why are you using POST data if your request method is GET?

Comment: its printing "none"

Comment: @EmilioConte here "form = LocForm(request.POST)" ?

Comment: Yes but here your GET.get() returns None and you cannot use **icontains** with None value. The error is clear. Use a try block.

Comment: @Satvik I'd have done ```if request.method.POST``` instead of ```if request.method.GET```.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said in comment you cannot use `icontains` with `None` value.  Try this:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            search_query = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
            if search_query:
                FirstLoc_list_obj = FirstLoc_List.objects.filter(address__icontains=search_query)
                SecondLoc_list_obj= SecondLoc_list.objects.filter(address__icontains=search_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an empty string if None, for example :

```
search_query = request.GET.get('search_box')

if not search_query :
    search_query = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only place that discuss this error. So this is not the perfect answer of the question, but i hope it will be usefull for others.

I don't have a form but a URL to check, but when a user get on the page on a way i didn't intend, it shouldn't raise an error. So i put everything inside a **if** statement.

```py
if request.GET.get("q") != None:
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        context["array"] = Database.objects.filter(DB__item__contains=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            enter code heresearch_query = request.GET.get('search_box', '')
            FirstLoc_list_obj = FirstLoc_List.objects.filter(address__icontains=search_query)
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the somewhat similar code in the accepted answer? What are the benefits of your approach? Can you [edit] your answer to provide more explanation like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have it in one line if you wish as:

```
    cat_list = ModelName.objects.filter(name__icontains="" if name is None else name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
query = request.POST.get("query", "")
all posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
params = {'all posts: allPosts}
```